# Timeseries of cheapest-to-deliver bonds from Bloomberg

Tags: futures, bloomberg

I am running a regression analysis on a `bond`x`day` panel to explain the variation in repo rates. The dependent variable is the weighted average rate of all repo transactions which are conducted on a specific `day` and which are collateralized with a specific `bond`. All considered (collateral) bonds are Eurozone government bonds. In this analysis, I want to control for cheapest-to-deliver (CTD) bonds.

To this end, I want to construct an indicator variable which identifies whether a bond in my sample is the CTD on a certain day. I am struggling to query this data from Bloomberg.

1. Are `Euro-Bund` (DE), `Euro-BONO` (ES), `Euro-OAT` (FR), `Euro-BTP` (IT) all future contracts I should consider for my sample of bonds?
2. From the BB-Excel Add-In, how can I obtain a daily series that indicates for a specific future contract which bond is the CTD? I know that in the Terminal I can, for example, type `RXA Comdty` and `CTD`, and look out for the bond with the highest `Implied Repo %` value.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ask Help Help (F1 F1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to ask the Help Desk in my opinion.

`=BDH("RX1 COMB Comdty","FUT_CTD_CUSIP","20150101"," ")` in excel for example (works also with active or whatever future in the chain)

**Edit**

Yes, on the terminal it is HCTD - that formula pulls the same info. You cannot do all contracts in a chain at once (that I know of). The generics are always "chaining" them together. =BDH("RX1 Comdty","FUT_CUR_GEN_TICKER","20150101"," ") shows the contracts associated with the generic at the specific date.

If you need all, there are a few ways. `RXA Comdty DES` shows (or also `CT` page) shows you that there is only H, M, U, and Z for quarters and the associated year.
RXH, RXM, with RXM19, RXM12 for June 2012. Should be easy to loop through if needed. `=BDS("RX1 Comdty","FUT_CHAIN", "CHAIN_DATE=20180713"` gives you the entire chain at a given date. Depends what you feel works better I suppose.

Comment: Just for the record: in terminal, you can load the specific future contract, e.g. `RXZ19 Comdty`, then look for `HCTD` (Historical CTD) and extract this to an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: This works, thanks. I did contact the help desk and they claimed I needed to go via the Terminal, but I verified your procedure. However, it seems that I have to query the time series for a specific future contract, e.g. `RXZ17 Comdty`, but not for all contracts in a chain at once. Is this correct?

Comment: @Edit: As a newcomer to Bloomberg, I took a more manual approach with the Terminal to collect all future contracts relevant to my project and eventually queried CTD through Excel. Thanks for the explanations, though, I am sure I will need it in the future.